# PyPi Keyboard - Seeing "Shortcut" characters printed on break from their loop?

Tags: python

```
import keyboard
import os
import sys
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style, init
init()
clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
cwd = os.getcwd()
header = """
   ____      _          ____      _       _       _                ___   _
  / ___|___ (_)_ __    / ___|__ _| |_   _| | __ _| |_ ___  _ __   / _ \\ / |
 | |   / _ \\| | '_ \\  | |   / _` | | | | | |/ _` | __/ _ \\| '__| | | | || |
 | |__| (_) | | | | | | |__| (_| | | |_| | | (_| | || (_) | |    | |_| || |
  \\____\\___/|_|_| |_|  \\____\\__,_|_|\\__,_|_|\\__,_|\\__\\___/|_|     \\___(_)_|
                                                   Omar "Michael Abdo" 2019
                                                                'Q' to Quit
"""


def end():
    print(Style.BRIGHT + Fore.RED + "\n\n\t\tCLOSING.")
    os._exit(0)

def commit(cs, vs, opened="CoinCount"):
    inp = ""
    total = "\n\nTOTAL ${0:.2f}".format(sum(map(lambda x, y: x*y, cs, vs)))
    while inp.upper() != "N" and inp.upper() != "Y":
        inp = input("{} Save? [Y/N]: ".format(total))
    if inp.upper() == "Y":
        temp = input("Enter filename or press enter to use default ({}).txt:  ".format(opened))
        if temp: opened = temp
        if not opened.endswith(".txt"): opened += ".txt"
        conf = ""
        while conf.upper() not in ['Y', 'N']:
            conf = input("Saving file as {}\\{} - Confirm? [Y/N]: ".format(cwd, opened))
        if conf.upper() == "Y":
            with open(opened, "w+") as f:
                f.write(",".join(map(lambda x: str(x), cs)))
                f.write(total)
            clear()
            print("Total saved to {}\\{}!\n\n\n\n".format(cwd, opened))
    end()

def changeVal(dir, cursor_pos, cs, vs):
    ch = (len(cs) - 1) - cursor_pos[0]
    if dir == "D":
        if cs[ch] >= 1:
            cs[ch] -= 1
            moveCursor('n', cursor_pos, cs, vs)
    elif dir == "U":
            cs[ch] += 1
            moveCursor('n', cursor_pos, cs, vs)

def moveCursor(dir, cursor_pos, cs, vs):
    total = "TOTAL ${0:.2f}".format(sum(map(lambda x, y: x*y, cs, vs)))
    neutral = """



        0.05    0.10    0.25    1.00    2.00    5.00    10.00   20.00   50.00   100.00

         {}       {}       {}       {}       {}       {}        {}       {}       {}        {}

                """.format(cs[9], cs[8], cs[7], cs[6], cs[5], cs[4], cs[3], cs[2], cs[1], cs[0])
    if dir != 'n':
        if cursor_pos[0] != 0 and dir == 'L':
            cursor_pos[0] -= 1
        elif cursor_pos[0] != 9 and dir == 'R':
            cursor_pos[0] += 1
        elif cursor_pos[0] == 0 and dir == 'L':
            cursor_pos[0] = 9
        elif cursor_pos[0] == 9 and dir == 'R':
            cursor_pos[0] = 0
    clear()
    print(total)
    if cursor_pos[0] == 0:
        print(neutral[:12] + Style.BRIGHT + Fore.GREEN + neutral[12:16] + Style.RESET_ALL + neutral[16:]) #Nickel
    elif cursor_pos[0] == 1:
        print(neutral[:20] + Style.BRIGHT + Fore.GREEN + neutral[20:24] + Style.RESET_ALL  + neutral[24:]) #Dime
    elif cursor_pos[0] == 2:
        print(neutral[:28] + Style.BRIGHT + Fore.GREEN + neutral[28:32] + Style.RESET_ALL  + neutral[32:]) #Quarter
    elif cursor_pos[0] == 3:
        print(neutral[:36] + Style.BRIGHT + Fore.GREEN + neutral[36:40] + Style.RESET_ALL  + neutral[40:]) #loon
    elif cursor_pos[0] == 4:
        print(neutral[:44] + Style.BRIGHT + Fore.GREEN + neutral[44:48] + Style.RESET_ALL  + neutral[48:]) #toon
    elif cursor_pos[0] == 5:
        print(neutral[:52] + Style.BRIGHT + Fore.GREEN + neutral[52:56] + Style.RESET_ALL  + neutral[56:]) #fiver
    elif cursor_pos[0] == 6:
        print(neutral[:60] + Style.BRIGHT + Fore.GREEN + neutral[60:65] + Style.RESET_ALL  + neutral[65:]) #tens
    elif cursor_pos[0] == 7:
        print(neutral[:68] + Style.BRIGHT + Fore.GREEN + neutral[68:73] + Style.RESET_ALL  + neutral[73:]) #twenties
    elif cursor_pos[0] == 8:
        print(neutral[:76] + Style.BRIGHT + Fore.GREEN + neutral[76:81] + Style.RESET_ALL  + neutral[81:]) #fifties
    elif cursor_pos[0] == 9:
        print(neutral[:84] + Style.BRIGHT + Fore.GREEN + neutral[84:91] + Style.RESET_ALL  + neutral[91:]) #hundreds
    print("CONTROLS:\n-> / <-\t:\tMOVE\nZ\t:\tINCREMENT\nX\t:\tDECREMENT\nENTER\t:\tSAVE\nQ\t:\tQUIT")
def main():
    print(Fore.GREEN + Style.BRIGHT + header)
    keyboard.add_hotkey('q', end)
    mode = ""
    cursor_pos = [0]
    cs = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] #100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1, 0.25, 0.10, 0.05
    vs = [100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1, 0.25, 0.10, 0.05]
    while mode != "C" and mode != "S":
        mode = input("Enter mode for entry: C for Counting, S for Static: ")
        if mode.upper() == "S":
            hund = ""
            while not hund.isdigit():
                hund = input("Enter # of $100:\t")

            fift = ""
            while not fift.isdigit():
                fift = input("Enter # of $50:\t\t")

            twen = ""
            while not twen.isdigit():
                twen = input("Enter # of $20:\t\t")

            tens = ""
            while not tens.isdigit():
                tens = input("Enter # of $10:\t\t")

            five = ""
            while not five.isdigit():
                five = input("Enter # of $5:\t\t")

            toon = ""
            while not toon.isdigit():
                toon = input("Enter # of $2:\t\t")

            loon = ""
            while not loon.isdigit():
                loon = input("Enter # of $1:\t\t")

            quar = ""
            while not quar.isdigit():
                quar = input("Enter # of $0.25:\t")

            dime = ""
            while not dime.isdigit():
                dime = input("Enter # of $.10:\t")

            nick = ""
            while not nick.isdigit():
                nick = input("Enter # of $0.05:\t")

            save = ""
            while save.upper() != "Y" and save.upper() != "N":
                save = input("Total is ${}. Save amount?\n\n\t\t[Y/N]:\t".format(int(nick)*0.05 + int(dime)*0.10 + int(quar)*0.25 + int(loon)*1 + int(toon)*2 + int(five)*5 + int(tens)*10 + int(twen)*20 + int(fift)*50 + int(hund)*100))
            if save.upper() == "Y":
                conf = ""
                while conf.upper() not in ['Y', 'N']:
                    if os.path.exists("CoinCount.txt"):
                        inp = input("File exists. Enter a new name or press enter to overwrite default file CoinCount.txt: ")
                    else:
                        inp = input("Enter filename or press enter to use default (CoinCount.txt):  ")
                    if not inp: inp = "CoinCount"
                    if not inp.endswith(".txt"): inp += ".txt"
                    conf = input("Saving file as {}\\{}- Confirm? [Y/N]: ".format(cwd, inp))
                    if conf.upper() == "N":
                        conf = ""
                        continue
                    if conf.upper() == "Y":
                        with open(inp, "w+") as f:
                            f.write(",".join(list(map(lambda x: str(x),[hund, fift, twen, tens, five, toon, loon, quar, dime, nick]))))
                            f.write("\n{}".format(int(nick)*0.05 + int(dime)*0.10 + int(quar)*0.25 + int(loon)*1 + int(toon)*2 + int(five)*5 + int(tens)*10 + int(twen)*20 + int(fift)*50 + int(hund)*100))
                    clear()
                print("Total saved to {}\\{}!\n\n\n\n".format(cwd, inp))
            end()
        elif mode.upper() == "C":
            mode = ""
            inp = ""
            while mode.upper() != "N" and mode.upper() != "O":
                mode = input("Count from New or Open previous total? [N/O]: ")
            if mode.upper() == "O":
                if os.path.exists("CoinCount.txt"):
                    inp = input("File(s) exist. Enter a new name or press enter to use the default CoinCount.txt: ")
                else:
                    inp = input("Enter filename:  ")
                if not inp: inp = "CoinCount"
                if not inp.endswith(".txt"): inp += ".txt"
                conf = ""
                while conf.upper() not in ['Y', 'N']:
                    conf = input("Open from {}\\{} - Confirm? [Y/N]: ".format(cwd, inp))
                if conf.upper() == "Y":
                    try:
                        with open(inp) as f:
                            cs = list(map(lambda x: int(x), f.readline()[:-1].split(",")))
                            print("Successfully loaded data from {}\\{}".format(cwd, inp))
                    except:
                        print("BAD!")
            moveCursor('n', cursor_pos, cs, vs)
            keyboard.add_hotkey('left', moveCursor, args=('L', cursor_pos, cs, vs))
            keyboard.add_hotkey('right', moveCursor, args=('R', cursor_pos, cs, vs))
            keyboard.add_hotkey('z', changeVal, args=('U', cursor_pos, cs, vs))
            keyboard.add_hotkey('x', changeVal, args=('D', cursor_pos, cs, vs))
            keyboard.add_hotkey('enter', commit, args=(cs, vs, inp))
            while True:
                pass
main()
```

Context: 
This is a coin calculating Python script that uses PyPi Keyboard to allow a user to use the "Z" and "X" keys to increment a selected coin (Choosen by moving the highlighted coin with arrows) while in "C[ount]" mode. It works! The problem is that when I increment some coins and go to save the result by running "commit" thereby breaking the `While True` loop...
[image: Shortcut Keys Returned]

It prints the keys I was pressing to Increment. Could anyone tell me why? I've narrowed it down to this section in `commit`:

```
def commit(cs, vs, opened="CoinCount"):
    inp = ""
    total = "\n\nTOTAL ${0:.2f}".format(sum(map(lambda x, y: x*y, cs, vs)))
    while inp.upper() != "N" and inp.upper() != "Y":
        inp = input("{} Save? [Y/N]: ".format(total))
```

This because when I add a 'debugging string' like "WWEEEEOOO WWEEEOOO" to that loop I get:
[image: Alarm Sounding]
Which I take to mean that it has entered my `While`loop three(?) times in total instead of once. Please let me know if you have insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to CodeReview. I'll point out that posting code and asking questions about a bug you have makes your post *Off Topic,* since this site is for reviews of working code.

With that out of the way, I'll review your code:

## The bug

The `keyboard` functions take a parameter called `suppress`. I believe that if you set `suppress=True` on your various hotkey definitions, it will cause the `keyboard` module to eliminate the key events entirely after calling your callback function. **However,** I was unable to get this working on my machine, so I don't know what's going on.

So, perhaps you would consider abandoning the use of the `keyboard` module for this purpose. There is another option for doing responsive keyboard-driven terminal work: [`curses`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/curses.html). Or you might consider [`pygame`](https://www.pygame.org) if you just want to catch the keyboard events and use `stdout` for your output.

## The review:

I found your code quite dense and not well organized. However, it was fairly straightforward, with the exception of the hotkey mechanism supplied by the `keyboard` module, and comprehensible.

#### 1. Follow the [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) guidelines.

PEP-8 is the Python style guide. It tells you how to organize `import` statements and name variables and functions. It gives useful examples of code and coding style. Reformatting and changing some names in this manner will improve your code's readability by 10-20%.

```
import os
import sys

import keyboard
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style, init

clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
cwd = os.getcwd(
header = """    ... etc ...    """
```

#### 2. Moar functions!

Your code is split into functions. But it's not split into *enough* functions. So, write some more! For example:

```
while inp.upper() != "N" and inp.upper() != "Y":
    inp = input("{} Save? [Y/N]: ".format(total))
if inp.upper() == "Y":
```

This code interrupts whatever you were doing to loop around chasing after a valid answer from the user. Then, it forces you to do one last string-case-conversion to decode what was supplied and branch on it.

How about just writing a function, `get_yn(prompt, default=None)` that does that looping and case-insensitive comparison for you, and returns a boolean value? And you can even make it accept a default if you want:

```
if get_yn("{} Save?".format(total)):
    ...
```

Here's another example:

```
if dir != 'n':
    if cursor_pos[0] != 0 and dir == 'L':
        cursor_pos[0] -= 1
    elif cursor_pos[0] != 9 and dir == 'R':
        cursor_pos[0] += 1
    elif cursor_pos[0] == 0 and dir == 'L':
        cursor_pos[0] = 9
    elif cursor_pos[0] == 9 and dir == 'R':
        cursor_pos[0] = 0
```

This just isn't very good code. First, you're checking if `dir != 'n'` but inside the block, every conditions *checks the value of `dir` again!* So that outer check isn't needed. Second, you have two different cases for handling the `L` and `R` directions, and the two cases are separate. Finally, you have just enough complexity that it deserves some functions:

```
if dir == 'L':
    cursor_pos = move_l(cursor_pos)
elif dir == 'R':
    cursor_pos = move_r(cursor_pos)
```

#### 3. Don't use built-in functions or types as variable names:

Don't do this:

```
def changeVal(dir, cursor_pos, cs, vs):
    ch = (len(cs) - 1) - cursor_pos[0]
    if dir == "D":
```

Add or subtract a letter to avoid using `dir` as a parameter name. You could use `direction` or `dirn` or `updown`.

#### 4. Use names to provide appropriate information

In that same example,

```
def changeVal(dir, cursor_pos, cs, vs):
    ch = (len(cs) - 1) - cursor_pos[0]
```

What are `cs, vs,` and `ch`? For that matter, what is `cursor_pos` since I notice that its value ranges from 0 to 9. Clearly, it's not actually a cursor position...

#### 5. Use [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html?highlight=slice#slice) objects to make your code more data-driven

You write:

```
if cursor_pos[0] == 0:
    print(neutral[:12] + Style.BRIGHT + Fore.GREEN + neutral[12:16] + Style.RESET_ALL + neutral[16:]) #Nickel
elif cursor_pos[0] == 1:
    print(neutral[:20] + Style.BRIGHT + Fore.GREEN + neutral[20:24] + Style.RESET_ALL  + neutral[24:]) #Dime
# ... many more lines ...
```

But what you really want to do is this:

```
column = cursor_pos[0]
print("{pre_fields}{hilight}{active_field}{normal}{post_fields}".format(
    hilight=Style.BRIGHT + Fore.GREEN,
    normal=Style.RESET_ALL,
    pre_fields=neutral[pre_fields[column]],
    active_field=neutral[active_field[column]],
    post_fields=neutral[post_fields[column]]))
```

You can define slice objects like this, which doesn't actually work because the columns are varying width.

```
pre_fields = [slice(None, 12 + 8 * i) for i in range(10)]
active_field = [slice(12 + 8 * i, 16 + 8 * i) for i in range(10)]
post_fields = [slice(16 + 8 * i, None) for i in range(10)]
```

But if you had an array of column headers, you could use that in the slice expressions.

#### 6. Support a more dynamic screen size.

My console is 80 columns wide. See?

```
austin [ /d/Devel/so ]$ echo $COLUMNS x $LINES
80 x 40
```

I'm using `console` and a version of `bash.exe` for Windows. And it naturally provides the environment variables that indicate screen size. If you're using `curses`, it figures things out somehow. If you use the python Windows bindings, I think you can determine the size of a `cmd` window.

So, do that. Instead of hard-coding your app to support 90 columns, or whatever setting you have (it isn't 80 columns, since the $100 column wraps on my console), make yourself an array of column headers, and column positions. Compute the positions when you start up, based on the available screen real estate.

#### 7. Use collections instead of individual variables

This code:

```
save = input("Total is ${}. Save amount?\n\n\t\t[Y/N]:\t".format(
    int(nick)*0.05 + int(dime)*0.10 + int(quar)*0.25 + int(loon)*1 
    + int(toon)*2 + int(five)*5 + int(tens)*10 + int(twen)*20 
    + int(fift)*50 + int(hund)*100))
```

is a great opportunity to write a function. But it's also using variables when you could be using a list. You already have lists called `vs` and `cs` (which I assume stand for `values` and `counts`. So why not use them?

```
def cash_value(counts, values):
    return sum(count * value for count, value in zip(counts, values))
```

8. Use `pathlib`

Instead of manually managing file paths, and printing `"{}\\{}".format(cwd, inp)`, use the standard library module [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/pathlib.html) to do it. It supports Windows and *nix slashes, knows about absolute vs. relative paths, and can be stringified in a nice way.

```
from pathlib import Path

cwd = Path('.')
save_file = cwd / filename

print("Saving data to '{}'".format(save_file.resolve())
```

Comment: Please wait for them to fix their code before reviewing it.